# Import org.apache statement cannot be resolved in GCP Shell

Tags: java, hadoop

I had used the below command in GCP Shell terminal to create a project wordcount

```
 mvn archetype:generate 
-DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maen.archetypes 
-DgroupId=com.wordcount 
-DartifactId=wordcount
```

and then added a Map java file in the below path /wordcount/src/main/java/com/wordcount.

When i'm using the below import statements it's throwing an error.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Intwritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
```

I'm unable to find the path in GCP shell am i missing the apache/hadoop classes which should be added so that i can resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest finding an archetype for creating MapReduce applications, otherwise, you need to [add `hadoop-client` as a dependency in your pom.xml](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-client)

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer,as mentioned Dependency was missing in pom.xml .